# Django CKEditor AllowedContent

Tags: django, ckeditor

Does anyone know how to get the advancedContentFilter working in the django-ckeditor config settings? Im trying to filter pasted in p tags to remove style attributes. Im using the following in settings.py but it does'nt seem to register.

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'allowedContent':'p',
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This works for me

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
  'default': {
    'removePlugins': 'stylesheetparser',
    'allowedContent': True,
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

CKEDITOR_CONFIGS is a dictionary of configs, not a config dictionary :D try:

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'allowedContent':'p',
    },
}
```

Comment: Also... if you want to disable ckeditor's Advanced Content Filter, you can set 'allowedContent': True in your settings.py file. The ckeditor documents have more information on its settings: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_acf

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to remove `stylesheetparser` plugin?

https://github.com/shaunsephton/django-ckeditor#if-you-want-to-use-allowedcontent

Answer (score 0):

> Django CKEditor

### It's works for me

you can add or remove tag according to your need,

and do True False which you want (attributes, styles, classes)

https://django-ckeditor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#if-you-want-to-use-allowedcontent

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {

    'removePlugins': 'stylesheetparser',
            
    'allowedContent': True,

    'allowedContent':{'ul div section ol a p ':{
                'attributes': True,
                'styles': True,
                'classes': False
                },
              
            }, 
    ......
    .......
    ......


}
}
```